# SQL Query - Design struggle

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am fairly new to SQL Server (2012) but I was assigned the project where I have to use it.
The database consists of one table (counted in millions of rows) which looks mainly like this:

```
Number (float)  Date (datetime) Status    (nvarchar(255))
999             2016-01-01 14:00:00.000   Error
999             2016-01-02 14:00:00.000   Error
999             2016-01-03 14:00:00.000   Ok
999             2016-01-04 14:00:00.000   Error
888             2016-01-01 14:00:00.000   Error
888             2016-01-02 14:00:00.000   Ok
888             2016-01-03 14:00:00.000   Error
888             2016-01-04 14:00:00.000   Error
777             2016-01-01 14:00:00.000   Error
777             2016-01-02 14:00:00.000   Error
```

I have to create a query which will show me only the phone numbers (one number per row so probably Group by number?) that meet the conditions:

1. Number reappears at least 3 times
2. Last two times (that has to be based on date; originally records are not sorted by date) has to be an Error

For example, in the table above the phone number that meets the criteria is only 888, beacuse for 999 2nd newest status is Ok and number 777 reoccurs only 2 times.

I will appreciate any kind of help!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `row_number()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select number
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by number order by date desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by number
having count(*) >= 3 and
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then status end) = 'Error' and
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then status end) = 'Error';
```

Note: `float` is a really, really bad type to use for the "number" column.  In particular, two numbers can look the same but differ in low-order bits.  They will produce different rows in the `group by`.

You should probably use `varchar()` for telephone numbers.  That gives you the most flexibility.  If you need to store the number as a number, then `decimal`/`numeric` is a much, much better choice than `float`.

Comment: Hi Gordon, Thank you for the answer, it works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

```
select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by Number, order by date desc) as times

FROM

(

    select Number, Date 
    From table
    where Number in
     ( 
       select Number
       from table
       group by Number
       having count (*) >3
) as ABC

WHERE ABC.times in (1,2) and ABC.Status = 'Error'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with CTE as
(
select t1.*, row_number() over(partition by t1.Number order by t1.date desc) as r_ord
from MyTable t1
)
select C1.*
from CTE C1
inner join 
(
select Number
from CTE
group by Number
having max(r_ord) >=3
) C2
on C1.Number = C2.Number
where C1.r_ord in (1,2)
and C1.Status = 'Error'
```